# Exponentiation function with randint variables

Tags: python

```
totalquestions = int(5)
while totalquestions > 0 :
    num1 = randint(0,9)
    num2 = randint(0,9)
    print(num1)
    print(num2)
    answer = input(str("What is num1 ** num2?"))
    if answer == (num1 ** num2):
        print("correct")
    else:
        print("false")
```

I'm trying to create a quiz program where the user is given 2 random numbers and has to find the correct exponentiation of the 2 numbers given. Whenever i try to run this program I always get a false print statement even if the value I've inputted is correct. Sorry if this has a very simple solution I'm still a noob at python.

Comment: use `int(answer = input(str("What is num1 ** num2?")))`

Comment: Did you mean: `answer = int(input("What is num1 ** num2?"))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`answer = input(str("What is num1 ** num2?"))`
By default, input returns a string. If you compare a string with an int, it will return false. The correct way would be
`answer = int(input(str("What is num1 ** num2?")))`

Answer (score 0):

Your need input to int:

```
answer = int( input(str("What is num1 ** num2?")) )
```